# Unknown data type issue with native query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

I want to execute a simple native query, but it does not work:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM table(schema.fn_name(?1,?2,?3))
ORDER BY col1,col2");

query.setParameter(1, 1193679);
query.setParameter(2, 1193679);
query.setParameter(3, 1193679);   

resultList = query.getResultList();
```

It's failing with the below error

> "message":"Unknown data type: ; SQL statement
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Comment: What about setting other 2 parameters?